# How I Group by using awk

Tags: awk

Good afternoon

I get a file with this structure:

```
$ cat test
LogStartOffset,alex,1,4
LogEndOffset,alex,1,4
Size,alex,1,0
LogStartOffset,alvaro1,1,2
LogEndOffset,alvaro1,1,2
Size,alvaro1,1,0
LogStartOffset,alvaro_prueba,1,0
LogEndOffset,alvaro_prueba,1,0
Size,alvaro_prueba,1,0
LogStartOffset,arquitectura_jenkins_creardocumentacion,0,348
LogEndOffset,arquitectura_jenkins_creardocumentacion,0,387
Size,arquitectura_jenkins_creardocumentacion,0,11011
LogStartOffset,alex,0,445
LogEndOffset,alex,0,498
Size,alex,0,54670
...
```

Where:

```
  the field 2 is the topic name
  the field 3 is the partition of the topic defined in the field 2 
  the field 1 is the characteristic of the topic and its partition 
  the field 4 is the value of the charasteristic.
```

For now I am working with 3 characteristics (maybe in the future it will be more): LogStartOffset, LogEndOffset and Size

I want a output file with this structure

topic,partition,LogStartOffset's Value,LogEndOffset's Value,Size's Value

So the file.out should be something like this:

```
topic,partition,LogStartOffset's Value,LogEndOffset's Value,Size's Value
alex,1,4,4,0
alvaro1,1,2,2,0
alvaro_prueba,1,0,0
arquitectura_jenkins_creardocumentacion,0,348,387,11011
alex,0,445,498,54670
.....
```

The idea is group by fields 2 and 3 (Topic and partition), because I don't know if the secuence of the field 1 is always the same.

I want to do it using awk but I don't know how to plan the grouping of fields 2 and 3 and regroup the data to have the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example has three characteristics for each topic-partition pair in the order logstartoffset, logendoffset and size. If the names, number and order of *Characteristics of the topic*  in the file is same for each topic-partition pair, then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{a[$2","$3] = a[$2","$3]","$4} END { for (i in a) print i a[i];}' test
```

will work. It does not generate the header line and it will not preserve order of topic-partition pairs in file. When I tested, the output was:

```
alvaro1,1,2,2,0
alvaro_prueba,1,0,0,0
alex,0,445,498,54670
arquitectura_jenkins_creardocumentacion,0,348,387,11011
alex,1,4,4,0
```